# Hive SQL - Flag, Case when

Tags: sql, hive, case

I have a table named 'test' with the below columns:
[image]
I am trying to flag based on, if click = 1 and impression = 1, for the same lead_id, which could be duplicated across multiple rows because each event (click or impression) is captured in a separate row due to their different dates of occurrence, then flag it as 1.

Query I have:

```
select click, imp, lead_id,
    case 
    when count(distinct lead_id) >1 and (click=1 and imp = 1) 
    then 1 
    else 0 
    end as flag
    from test
    group by click, imp, lead_id;
```

Output required:
[image]

So the flag only flags lead_id abc001 because it has a click and imp, on different dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the maximum of `click` and `imp` in each partition of `lead_id`. If they're equal to 1, flag them up. This should be slightly more efficient than summing over each partition.

```
select 
    *, 
    case when max(click) over (partition by lead_id) = 1 and
              max(imp) over (partition by lead_id) = 1
         then 1
         else 0
         end as flag
from test;
```

Comment: This worked very well. Thanks for suggesting this. But both ways, it returns the same output. May I ask, why use 'max' instead of 'sum' then?

Comment: max is faster than sum for obvious reasons :)

Comment: not so obvious imo. Do you have some benchmarks on Hive or other proof?

Comment: proof is left to the reader as an exercise... joking aside, I might have mixed up the performance of count/max - I've read that count is faster, but it might not be true for max...

Answer (score 0):

Use analytical function as follows:

```
select click, imp, lead_id, 
       case when sum(click) over (partition by lead_id) > 0
                 and sum(imp) over (partition by lead_id) > 0   
           then 1  
           else 0  
       end as flag 
  from test ;
```